# Paths between vertices of different objects

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, animation-nodes, path

My geometry nodes level is around 2/10, so almost a complete beginner. So far I didn't manage to find any video on the matter.

I need to create multiple paths between ALL the vertices of one icosphere to SOME of the vertices of another separate icosphere (that has more divisions and therefore more vertices).

So far I thought of instancing a curve line on each vertex of the first icosphere, and I wanted to use those as START POINTS for each path. I don't know how to set vertices of the second icosphere as END POINTS.

Another solution I thought of was to instance curves on the vertices of both spheres and join them afterwards; no luck tho.

Further down the line I will want to move (animate) instances positioned on the vertices of the first icosphere down their individual paths ending on the surface of the second icosphere.

I'm here:
[image]
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify to which *SOME* points we need to connect the edges, so I will assume, that points with the same ID are to be matched.

1. As you did correctly, instance curve lines on the points of the small sphere and realize them.
2. Sample the position of the large icosphere (with the same amount or more points) and reposition the **endpoints** of the curves. (Use the *Endpoint Selection* node and the *Set Position* node.)
3. If desired, convert the curves to a mesh, join them with the geometry of the small icosphere and optionally the large icosphere. Then merge the vertices by distance.

[image: result and node setup]

Comment: that's wonderful, thanks a lot!
I didn't specify which points cause I wanted to see if I could figure it out myself.
Anyway, imagine that the paths are leading towards an eyeball (bigger icosphere) but targeting only the cornea (a circular area on the left side of the eyeball).

Now, I want to move each object on each separate newly created path.
But I'm only managing to move them all together on a single path.

Comment: https://postimg.cc/PP1nqQFY

Comment: Sounds like a different (~ new post) question.